# how is jint slowing down pure clr code that it calls

Tags: c#, jint

I eventually pared this down to an incredibly simple test (from a huge 500,000 line system). When I run this test app

```
using Jint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var jint = new JintEngine();
            jint.DisableSecurity();
            jint.MaxStatements = 1000;
            jint.SetFunction("foo",new Action( Foo));
            jint.Run("foo();");
            Foo();
        }

        public static void Foo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("foo");

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int j = 0; j < 500000; j++)
            {
                var k = new Byte[50];
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this

```
foo
55150
foo
13279
```

Note that the only difference is that the first Foo invocation is called by jint, the second one is called directly. There is no jint / js/ etc involved in the loop in Foo. When called via jint it takes 2 to 3 times as long to run the code!

It feels like jint inserted something into the environment that slows things down when its in the stack but I cant see what. It has some CAS calls, I took those out, didnt make a difference. I am stumped.

It really feels like it that CAS stuff, but I can't get it to behave consistently.

Comment: Can you try to inverse the call order?

Comment: You are mentioning CAS calls but Jint 2 doesn't have any. Are you using the latest version from Nuget?

Comment: no - i am using old version, I will look at new one